# How to pass Airflow 'ds' default variable?

Tags: python, airflow

I'm new to Airflow and a bit confused with Default Variables. I have custom operator and I want to use `ds` in file name. 
    file_name = str(f) + '{{ ds }}' + str(ext)

The actual result I get is file{{ds}}.docx but I expect file2020-01-01.docx

Comment: Can you post the task itself, i.e how you pass `file_name` to your CustomOperaot ?

Answer (score 1):

The strings containing curly braces (*e.g.: `{{ ds }}`*) are templated values where Airflow renders certain operator attributes through Jinja2 templating, providing details regarding the current run.

This documentation outlines how to use templating in a custom operator: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/custom-operator.html#templating